# Is there any way to schedule mail sent from gmail smtp server using phpmailer?

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, gmail-imap

I can send mails from gmail account, using smtp. I can send mails upto 100 mails per day! I need to send over 300 mails at once. Is there a way to send more mails per day ? or can i schedule mails so that all the 300 mails will be delivered at once after 3 days ?

Any help would be highly appreciated , 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy a Google Workspace email (up to 2,000 emails per day) or use another provider dedicated for this task (Sendgrid or MailChimp)